# WiX issues building on VSTS

Tags: msbuild, wix, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm trying to get one of our projects building on Visual Studio Team Services.

The issue is with candle.exe, specifying "MsBuild x86" the build gets as far as the call to candle.exe then it hangs (it gets there within minutes, then will hang until VSTS terminates the build amlost an hour later).

If I run it with "MsBuild x64" it runs as far as the first time, but fails because it can't find candle.exe

> d:\a\1\s\Ref\Ext\WiX.3.5\Lib\wix2010.targets(1813,5): error MSB6003:
>   The specified task executable could not be run. The system cannot find
>   the file specified [d:\a\1\s\Configuration\install\Installer.wixproj]

While it complains about the wixproj, that file exists, and I'm fairly sure it's the candle.exe it can't find.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is it a upgraded project or newly created project? What's the version of that project (v3 or v4)? Can you share the log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug to true and queue build, then share the detail log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I ended up doing to fix this.

- Remove my locally installed version of wix (it was clouding the
  issue)
- Upgraded the version of wix that gets checkout with the repository on VSTS *(yes we should be using NuGet I know)*.
- Explicitly set a value `$(WixToolPath)`
- Explicitly set the ToolPath to `$(WixToolPath)` when building the wixproj
- Switch off ICE validation scripts for the build

The installers now run.